# About Installation Jre in Solaris 10

Tags: java, installation, solaris

I have a server with Solaris 10 and Sparc arch., in which i am not a root user, and it's no able to be. Where there is installed a another version of JDK.

And now I need to install another version of Java, 1.5.0.22, without modify the environment variables, PATH, CLASSPATH, and so on. So to do this, I downloaded the specific jdk-1_5_0_22-solaris-sparc.sh but the question is Will change the environment this file or only extract to specified folder the lib's, directories?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right path to success.

As a non-root user you can install as many JDKs as you like. When you execute something like `jdk-1_5_0_22-solaris-sparc.sh` (*) it will not change anything in your environment, just unpack it. So just go ahead.

Enjoy.

*) wauw, that's an old one!